# unable to ping VM on another machine within the same network

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, ping

I can't ping from one VM to another VM on different machine. Both are connecting on the same wifi.

- firewall has been disable
- ICMP enable
- Network connection = NAT

Answer (score 1):

change network connection to bridge mode.